# retrieve error message values from .properties file

Tags: spring, jsp, properties

i need to retrieve error message values for client side validation from messages.properties file and display it on a page. 
i used `<fmt:message key="uname.prop" />`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#userRegistrationDetails").validate({
      rules: {
        username: "required",
        email: {
        required : true,
        email : true
                },
      password: "required",
      confpass: {
        required :true,
        equalTo: "#password"
                 }
              },
    messages: {
        username: <fmt:message key="uname.prop" />,
        email: "Please enter valid email address",
        password: "Please enter the password",
        confpass: "Please enter the same password"
      }

    });
  });
```

in my form page.

i cannot use label attribute since it is not defined in spring.

Comment: What's your question? What "label attribute" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of the question, similar to how you have defined the message for username, why not do the same for email and other field?

```
messages: {
    username: <fmt:message key="uname.prop" />,
    email: "<fmt:message key="error.invalid.email"/>",
    password: "<fmt:message key="error.required.password"/>",
    ...
}
```

Comment: His whole problem was that the didn't quote it so that it end up as invalid Javascript like as `username: Please enter valid username` instead of `username: "Please enter valid username"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get quoted string, you should surround it with quotes:

```
username: "<spring:message code = 'uname.prop' javaScriptEscape = 'true' />",
```

Also note that since you are generating Javascript source, you need to apply the appropriate escaping. Javascript escaping is supported by `<spring:message>`, so it makes sense to use it rather than `<fmt:message>`.

Comment: `javaScriptEscape` is not part of [`fmt:message`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html), but [`spring:message`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.message).